# Notify ViewModel when user types a character on textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm developing a WPF with C#, .NET Framework 4.5.1 and MVVM pattern.

I have this `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="userName" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="23" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="231" 
    Margin="10,10,0,5" 
    Text="{Binding Path=UserName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And this is the property:

```
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="UserName" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string UserNamePropertyName = "UserName";

private string _userName = null;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the UserName property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public string UserName
{
    get
    {
        return _userName;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_userName == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        RaisePropertyChanging(UserNamePropertyName);
        _userName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(UserNamePropertyName);
        DoLoginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't get the new value until `TextBox` lost focus.

Is there any way to notify `ViewModel` when user types a character on `TextBox`?

Comment: It would have taken less time to look at the documentation for Binding than it took to write this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your binding, specify UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="userName" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="23" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="231" 
    Margin="10,10,0,5" 
    Text="{Binding Path=UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your binding,

I believe all you need to do is add "UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"" into the binding so it reads as follows:

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="userName" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="23" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="231" 
    Margin="10,10,0,5" 
    Text="{Binding Path=UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```